# Recursivity printing c++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    f(12345);
    return 0;
}

void f(long n)
{
    cout << n%10;
    if(n!=0)
    {
        f(n/100); cout <<n%10;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why calling f(12345) prints out "5310135", I just started learning recursivity and I can't understand how it prints that. I've compiled and runned the program so I know the value it prints. I'm stuck at 5310 and then I don't know how the last 3 digits appear, can someone explain it to me ?

Comment: `n/100` try to explain what this is doing. Also explain why you need `cout <<n%10;` twice.

Comment: It is calling function f with n/100 as paramter.

Comment: Without the last cout << n%10; the program will only print out 5310, I want to know why it prints out 5310135 using the second cout.

Comment: "It is calling function f with n/100" I can figure out that much. Why do you think this is the right thing to do?

Comment: Consider adding a newline on each print: cout <<n%10 << '\n'; it will help you to better understand what happens on each recursion

Comment: "Without the last cout << n%10; the program will only print out 5310" So you have no idea why your program doesn't work and try random modifications hoping one of them will magically make it correct, right? Guess what, this never works.

Comment: Can you please add to your question what the program is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

The second `cout` will be executed when the recursion unfolds, that is from last recursive call to first recursive call.

```
  f(12345)          
     print 5
     f(123) ----------> f(123)
     print 5                print 3
                            f(1)  -------->  f(1)
                            print 3             print 1
                                                f(0)  ----->   f(0)
                                                print 1           print 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the if condition. Inside 'if', f(n/100) is called which creates a separate execution tree. This separate execution tree when completed, immediately calls the next instructions, which in this case be 1, 3 and 5 respectively. [image]